# Keras model not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

**update:**
I am using keras:2.2.0
tensorflow:2.4.1
python 3.7.9

I am using keras Sequential model for cats vs dogs CNN, and I am having thus error followed by a lots of `<class 'int'>` , the tutorial I am following is in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13ofdma_Kz8)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D

os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'
pickle_in=open(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/x.pickle','rb')
x=pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in=open(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/y.pickle','rb')
y=pickle.load(pickle_in)

x=x/255 #scaling down features to [0,1]
print(x)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x,y,batch_size=4,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3)

model.save(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/Dogs_VS_Cats_CNN.model')
print("GPUs: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

And this is the error I am having: [UNKNOWN ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwqe4.png)

Comment: You error is not clear. You may have two problems; (1) training can not be run on GPU as there is problem with CUDA etc (please search on OS for help), or (2) even though you have GPU recognized by tensorflow but training cannot  be done. What is the shape of x, so I may test your code?

Comment: Do you want to use tf with GPU, did it work on other projects? Would it be enough to use CPU for now?

Comment: x is a numpy array dedicated for storing features,

Comment: ``` x=np.array(x).reshape(-1,img_size,img_size,1)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have problem in defining the first layer or with correct shapes of the input data. I'm not sure because do not know your data details. But, the working example code, including exemplified training in your case is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten,Input
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D

os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'
#pickle_in=open(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/x.pickle','rb')
#x=pickle.load(pickle_in)
#pickle_in=open(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/y.pickle','rb')
#y=pickle.load(pickle_in)

#Test data...
x=tf.random.uniform((16,16,3))
y=tf.random.uniform((1,1))

x=x/255 #scaling down features to [0,1]
print(x)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),input_shape=x.shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

#Let's create a sample training data...
x_train=tf.random.uniform((10,16,16,3))
y_train=tf.random.uniform((10,1))

model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=4,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3)

#model.save(r'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Python learning\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/Dogs_VS_Cats_CNN.model')
print("GPUs: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

#Just for example...
for kierros in range(5):
    n=10+kierros
    x_train=tf.random.uniform((n,16,16,3))
    y_train=tf.random.uniform((n,1))
    print("Now the model is ready to take in the real training data with input shape: ",x_train.shape, " and target shape: ",y_train.shape, " in case of ", len(y_train), " training examples...")

print("...etc.")
```

...first run the code and verify that you see the training works well and the output looks like:

[image]

...and if yes, then simply add your real data in, but take care that the input shape of the data is correct. As exemplified, if you have ten pictures of size 16x16x3 (very small RGB-images) then the training input data shape is (10,16,16,3), etc.

Comment: I am having an ERROR:graph = tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Comment: Which version of tf and keras are u using plz?

Comment: I use tf: 2.4.1 and keras: 2.4.3. To make the debugging more easy for youI'll update the answer with the code.